# Lazy Load Stackoverflow Exception

Tags: c#, lazy-loading

I'm new to lazy-loading and I've been trying to implement it in my program. However, my program is throwing a StackoverflowException for some reason. I'm not sure how to approach this issue.

```
public new Field this[int key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.Contains(key))
            {
                Field field = null;

                // The loading code of the field + assigning the field object.

                this.Add(field);
            }

            return this[key];
        }
    }
```

I do realize the last line `this[key]` will just return over and over again, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

My class is a KeyedCollection of `<int, Field>`.

Comment: post the rest of your code.

Comment: @iamkrillin The rest of the code is just querying for the database and getting the information for the field object, and a method that returns the key for a Field object.

Comment: post it anyway.  The bug is likely in that code block.

Comment: When you return return this[key]; then the method this[int key] would be called again and again --> stackoverflow exception. You should return a Field object instead.

Comment: @iamkrillin I debugged and the loading code is not the problem. It's actually fine. The problem is on `return this[key]`, which will just go over the block of code over and over again.

Comment: @Cory Can you show me an example?

Comment: Did you override `GetKeyForItem`?

Answer (score 4):

`KeyedCollection` has protected `Dictionary` property. It returns `IDictionary<TKey, TItem>` with all the items.

```
public new Field this[int key]
{
    get
    {
        if (!this.Contains(key))
        {
            Field field = null;

            // The loading code of the field + assigning the field object.

            this.Add(field);
        }

        return Dictionary[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line calls the getter again, which causes a recursive call. Since there is no stopping condition, it fills up the stack's memory, hence the exception :

```
return this[key];
```

Try to do something like:

```
return this.GetItem(key);
```

Comment: @Cory I still have to get it through the overrriden key, not by the index, so that wouldn't help me.